# Calling an external API causes Bad Request if request contains JSON as a request parameter

Tags: json, spring, api, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I'm trying to integrate an external API to my Spring MVC application using RestTemplate.

It works perfectly fine unless I don't have to pass JSON as request parameter to API call. Such an attempt causes `400 Bad Request` every time, and as far as I checked in the API logs, my JSON parameter isn't decoded by the API (it still looks like encoded String).

I think it might be related somehow to the headers in my request, but once I added `Accept` and `Content-Type`, the error is still the same. Could someone give me an advice what might be wrong with my implementation?

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
body.add("Accept", "application/json");

UriComponentsBuilder urlBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url);

String encodedParamValue = URLEncoder.encode(paramValue, "UTF-8");
urlBuilder.queryParam(requestParam, encodedParamValue);

HttpEntity<?> getRequest = new HttpEntity<>(body);

String response = template.exchange(urlBuilder.build().toString(), HttpMethod.GET, getRequest, String.class).getBody();
```

**Fact 1** I'm pretty sure that the URL my code produces after concatenating the API endpoint and request parameter is OK, because the documentation shows exactly the same URL for same parameters.

**Fact 2** If I call a different endpoint that doesn't requires any parameters (just plain endpoint) then it works fine, so I assume that the way I call the API is OK.

**Fact 3** Like I mentioned, the API logs show that the API "can't" translate (decode) the parameter to JSON once I encoded it `URLEncoder.encode(paramValue, "UTF-8")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can folow this:

```
 try {
        .......
        .......  
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        // Set more header params as required ....
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, type);

        if(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
             //TODO: Need to modify response according to the demand
            if(response.getBody().getOk().equals("true") && response.getBody().getMessage() == null) {
                response.getBody().setMessage(successMessage);
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    .......
    .......
```

Comment: what does it change comparing to my code above? The result is anyway the same.